# Avoiding errors when calling methods on child associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails application where a user has many events.

If a user has an event and I do `current_user.events.each` then all is fine, although if the user doesn't have any events an undefined method error is thrown and the entire application stops working.

As a PHP user, I would first check if the variable was set before doing the loop. Does Rails have a nifty way of either initiating the method in the model regardless or should I still check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
current_user.events.try(:each)
```

This will simply return the regular output of `each` if `events` is not nil, and will return `nil` otherwise -- without erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if current_user.events  # This ensures that that the user at least has 1 event
  current_user.events.each 
  # rest of the code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

with newer versions of rails this shouldn't happen with blank arrays (provided you have an array).

there's always `.empty?`

```
if !current_user.events.empty?
  ..
end
```

Comment: Negative operators hurt Ruby's readability which is so precious. Better to use `.present?` in this case.

Comment: a fair point, but it's doing the same thing behind the scenes ;)